# Softlayer API To get a particular Storage ID for a particular Order ID

Tags: api, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

After placing order for a storage in softlayer, I need to get that storage id for a particular order id.The api call i am using, is giving me a list of storage ID. But, if user orders for a storage, only one storage id the user should get right.
So, the api is not properly filtering and not getting a particularly storage id for a particular order id . The rest api, i am using is given below and please tell me what should be the proper filtering ,
"https://[username]:[apikey]@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Account/getIscsiNetworkStorage.json?objectFilter={"networkStorage": {"billingItem": {"nasType": { "operation": "ISCSI"}, "orderItem": {"order": {"id":{"operation":"[orderID]"}}}}}} "

This api is provided by softlayer team

Regards,
Debartha

Comment: the rest api is working fine, but sometimes rest api is giving no response, so storage id coming undefined for that. Its happening irregularly not continuously. For example, storage size 100 & IOPS size 100 for performance storage ordering, the response is null, but not for everytime, FOr endurance also sometimes its coming null response.

Comment: Please, help me out here.

Comment: For your testing , i am providing the order id, 9653341

Comment: this rest api i used for performance storage order, storage size i chose 100 and iops size is 1500

Comment: but the response was nothing

Comment: FYI, in first comment in example the storage size was 100 & IOPS size was 1500 not 100.

Comment: The rest api is https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Account/getIscsiNetworkStorage.json?objectMask=mask[billingItem[orderItem[order]]]&objectFilter={"iscsiNetworkStorage": {"billingItem": { "orderItem": {"order": {"id":{"operation":"9622529"}}}}}}

Comment: fyi, i tried again to order a storage, with iops 1500 and storage size 100, then i got storage id. So, its happening irregularly. Please help me out here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this request:

```
    GET https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Account/getIscsiNetworkStorage?objectMask=mask[billingItem[orderItem[order]]]&objectFilter={"iscsiNetworkStorage": {"billingItem": { "orderItem": {"order": {"id":{"operation":5208963}}}}}}

note: replace 5208963, with your orderID
```

Basically all the devices must have a billingItem and that billingItem should have orderItem.order.id property, so you can use this filter to get any device using the orderID property, you just to need to make sure that the "iscsiNetworkStorage" value, in the filter, has the same name as the method you are calling (in this case getIscsiNetworkStorage method ), but without the pre-fix "get" and it must start with lower case e.g.

getIscsiNetworkStorage -> iscsiNetworkStorage

Regards

Comment: the rest api is working fine, but sometimes rest api is giving no response, so storage id coming undefined for that. Its happening irregularly not continuously. For example, storage size 100 & IOPS size 1500 for performance storage ordering, the response is null, but not for everytime, FOr endurance also sometimes its coming null response

Comment: For your testing , i am providing the order id, 9653341

Comment: when you order a device this device must be approved and provisioned, once all those steps are done, the request will work. So if you get a null response that means that your device is not ready yet, you just need to wait some time and try again.